# Two correlated marginally Gaussian RV, but not Jointly Gaussian

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, independence

We know if two RVs are marginally Gaussian and uncorrelated, they can be not jointly Gaussian. How about two **correlated RVs** which are **marginally Gaussian**? Are they Jointly Gaussian or no, there are occasions when they are not Jointly Gaussian?

Comment: Are you asking for an example where $X$ is normal, $Y$ is normal, $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \neq 0$ and $(X,Y)$ not jointly normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $U,V$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1).$ Let $(X,Y)=(U,U)$ if $U>0$ and let $(X,Y)=(-|U|,-|V|)$ if $U\le0.$

Or let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and let $(X,Y)=(Z,Z)$ if $|Z|>1$ and let $(X,Y)=(Z,-Z)$ if $|Z|\le 1.$

(Note: this second example edited 27 Jan 2024, correcting a mistake pointed out by Weltschmertz in a comment.)

In both cases, $X$ and $Y$ are marginally gaussian, correlated, but not jointly gaussian.

Comment: Your first example is correct but it seems like the second one isn't, as $Y$ doesn't take values in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Weltschmerz Thank you for pointing this out.